# Workflow rule - send email alert

Tags: apex, workflow

I need to send an email to a particular email address. I thought it would be nice to use the workflow rules.

I could not find the proper implementation to enter a particular email address to send the alert. What I can see is already created record I can select from, but I do not need this.

I have attached a screenshot so you can see from where I am trying to do this implementation.

[image]

Can you point me to the right place?

Note: I am thinking what I need to achieve is not possible over workflow rules, but only over triggers, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If particular email address is getting captured as an `email` field of an object, you can select that from the drop-down.

[image: Email Receipients]

Otherwise, you can specify that email address in `Additional Emails` section.

Comment: I want to enter a particular email address, and this email address is not available in any record in the system

Comment: put that email address in additional email section

Comment: please close this question

Comment: Question closed :)